# Request payload NOT present in PUT Request

Tags: api, node.js, rest, put, iisnode

implementing a REST API server, when capturing PUT requests , the body of the message is empty

Server: Windows Server Web SP2 
IIS: ver 7.0.6000.16386
node v0.8.16 
iisnode v0.2.2

test code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var data = '';
    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
        console.log(data)
    });
    request.on("end", function(){
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        response.end(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you using to send the PUT? What happens exactly? Does the `console.log` never run? More info would be great. The code looks fine as far as I can see. You should add a `request.setEncoding('utf8')` in there, but that wouldn't cause what you describe.

Comment: @loganfsmyth We are updating a REST resource through a PUT method. We are using Microsoft urlRewrite module to capture the http requests by the app.js entry point of our node.js app (as described here [link](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-express-nodejs-applications-in.html). We are using the restify node module for the creation of the rest services. Apparently this urlRewrite module does not forward the message body. Nevertheless hosting the same app in IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2) does not raise this issue.

Comment: Cool, so you are saying this is due to a bug in Microsoft urlRewrite? If you put that in a answer that would be great, so this doesn't sit here without an official answer.

Comment: But yopu're using UrlRewrite in iis 7.5 as well, what version of url rewrite do you have installed?